# ¿como cuento los numeros o como le hago para hacer que no se me genere un registro nuevo en processing?

Tags: processing

mi duda es la siguiente estoy intentando de guardar las puntuaciones maximas de un juego que estoy haciendo en processing pero el problema que al guardarlo en un txt el problema es que me genera una nueva linea en de texto en vez de contar todos los resultados y solo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ponerlo en una linea de texto, el codigo que estoy manejando para que guarde esta parte es el siguiente  `output.println("el puntaje que obtuviste es de "+(puntaje) );` existe alguna forma que en vez de que haga eso me genere algo como "el puntaje que obtuviste es de 3 " pero sin poner el registro del 1 y del 2?

Comment: Es posible que estés haciendo el print dentro del blucle de más bajo nivel, puedes mostrarnos tu código porfa?

Comment: claro te dejo el enlace donde puedes descargarlo para verlo mucho mejor https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zAwSjcch20juPRmIt8LAMQoo9Sei2sNE